# Vagrant docker provisioner doesn't start containers on boot

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrant-provision

I use Docker provisioner for Vagrant. They say in the [docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/docker.html):

> In addition to pulling images, the Docker provisioner can run and
>   start containers for you. This lets you automatically start services
>   as part of vagrant up.

Here's a part of my Vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|                                                                         
    d.run "jwilder/nginx-proxy",                                                                              
      args: "-v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro -v /vagrant/certs:/etc/nginx/certs -p 80:80 -p 443:443"
    d.run "redis",                                                                                            
      args: "-v /vagrant/data:/data"                                                                          
    ...
  end
```

But after `vagrant halt` and then `vagrant up` my containers are stopped.

```
$vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID    ..  STATUS      ..             NAMES
6bb965d1a7b9        Exited (137) 2 days ago    redis                 
7f45214f6f06        Exited (2) 2 days ago      jwilder-nginx-proxy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't find the reason why Vagrant doesn't start containers on boot, but the workaround is to use Docker's [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart). So, I updated my Vagrantfile, removed all the containers and did `vagrant provision` to run containers again with new restart policies:

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|                                                                         
  d.run "jwilder/nginx-proxy",                                                                              
    args: "--restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro -v /vagrant/certs:/etc/nginx/certs -p 80:80 -p 443:443"
  d.run "redis",                                                                                            
    args: "--restart=always -v /vagrant/data:/data"                                                                          
  ...
end
```

> **--restart=always**
>
> Always restart the container regardless of the exit status. When you
>   specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container
>   indefinitely.

Now after `vagrant halt` and then `vagrant up` containers are started.